# Broken Pipe Exception

Tags: java, haskell

I have written a server in Haskell which passes messages to connected clients. If the connection drops from one of the clients, it takes several minutes for my server to notice that the client is gone. `hGetLine` in Haskell is blocking and I can't close the thread if it's still listening (there is a way with async, but it's not working for me). If I write to the broken pipe from that client, I get a broken pipe exception in Java and have to make a new socket. Implementing heartbeats to check if the connection is still open could work, but if there are two telnet sessions connected to the server, it's nearly impossible to instantly reply on a heartbeat message from the server.

Is there any way to notice quickly if the client is disconnected? Is there a way to use `SIG_IGN` to ignore the broken pipe exception in Java and write to the same pipe after Internet connectivity is restored?

Comment: How is the `async` method not working?

Comment: hGetLine blocks. After it has some input, the thread is cancelled.